# How to call a c# dll from java program

Tags: c#, java, dll

I have a c# dll that needs to be called in Java.I see that there is a method using jni to call c++ dlls.How can I do it for a c# dll..Please help..I couldnt find any good material on this

Comment: Have you tried writing a C++ DLL to wrap the C# dll?

Comment: Yes,I have looked into it..Should I use COM for that?Is it the only method available?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.ikvm.net/):-

> IKVM.NET is an implementation of Java for Mono and the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework. It includes the following components:
>
> - A Java Virtual Machine implemented in .NET
> - A .NET implementation of the Java class libraries
> - Tools that enable Java and .NET interoperability

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). Or you can create a COM assembly from the C# code and use [J-Interop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-interop/) to invoke it.

If you have C# dll sources you need to use maybe the better way will be to translate it to Java using some tools like [GrassHopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=130).

According to GrassHopper key feature explanation it can convert MSIL to Java bite code. So can use without sources of c# dll

[image: MSIL]

Comment: I dont have access to the c# code,I am just given the dll..wHich one would be a better way for me?

Comment: You can use both JNI or J-Interop. I`ve tried them both. JNI was better for my task. But its just my opinion.

Comment: GrassHopper can conver to bytecode MSIL, so you don`t need c# code. Added it to answer

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://www.javonet.com

If you look for quick and easy solution then Javonet should work fine for you. It is light counterpart of IKVM and J-Integra works also as native bridge.

All you have to do is:

1. add Javonet.jar do your project call
2. call Javonet.addReference("yourlib.dll")
3. use your .NET library like it was almost JAVA package

**Sample:**

```
NObject obj = Javonet.New("yourDotNetClass");
obj.invoke("YourMethod","arg1", 2);
```

The syntax is not strongly-typed and works like reflection but gives you fastest access to any custom .NET code, third-party libs or .NET framework as no changes are needed on .NET side. If you need it is also possible to implement custom strongly-typed wrappers.

I do recommend this bridge as in my opinion it is easiest to quickly get things done but also other native bridges are worth checking as this is best approach for such case.

I would avoid going into custom JNI or COM unless you have a lot of time and you just want to learn, if you need quick and reliable solution take one of third-party bridges.